# directory class not working php & xmapp

Tags: php, xampp, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a file directory but problem is my index page loads but its a blank page. below is what I have

```
index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
<?php
require_once  ("../app/views/nav.php");
<body
<p> test </p>
</body
</html> 
?>

nav.php
<div>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="<?php fetchdir($views); ?>">TEST</a>
</li> 
</ul>

directories.class.php
  class directories{
    function __construct(){
    //I am not using a database so I don't know what to put here
    }

    function fetchdir($dir) {

        $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'; // The website host 
        $protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') === FALSE ? 'http://' : 'https://'; //The HTTP(S) protocol 
        $branch = ""; // Dirs in URL from host to main folder

        $protocol = $GLOBALS['protocol'];
        $host = $GLOBALS['host'];
        echo $protocol.$host.$branch.$dir;
    }

}

$views = "views/";
 $root = new directories;
```

When I try to load the page. I get a blank page but as soon as i `remove`

```
<a href="<?php fetchdir($views); ?>">TEST</a>
```

the page loads.

**additional info**

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  DocumentRoot "c:\Users\MYNAME\web-test\teDt202\web\html" 
  ServerName teDt202.local 
  <Directory c:\Users\MYNAME\web-test\teDt202\web> 
    # Apache 2.2 style access control (DEFAULT)  
    # Order allow,deny  
    # Allow from all 

    # Apache 2.4 style access contol (comment the next line if you're using below Apache 2.4)  
    Require all granted  

    AllowOverride all 
  </Directory> 
  AddHandler php5-script .htm 

  Alias /main c:\Users\MYNAME\web-test\teDt202\web\main
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteRule /(.*)$ /main/index.php/$1 [NS,PT,L] 

</VirtualHost>
```

**folder sturture**

```
teDt202 <---main folder
web 
app
  classes <!-- all my class files are in here
  views <!-- I have all my .php files are in here
html <!-- I have my css, js and images files here
main
 index.php
```

please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function called `fetchdir()` but it resides within a class, therefore you cannot call the function directly without first instantiating this class, and then calling the function as a method of the class its self.

```
$directories = new directories;

<a href="<?php $directories->fetchdir($views); ?>">TEST</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay I did instantiate the class but 2 things happens 1) my page loads without the css and

Comment: 2) when i click on a link in the nav i get something like this `http://teDt202.local/%3Cbr%20/%3E%3Cb%3ENotice%3C/b%3E:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20protocol%20in` blah blah blah

Comment: @user3057514 That's an error. You can see within this that it is an error. `undefined index protocol`.